# Filtering rows by `df.str.split` on columns in pandas

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame looks like the following

```
url1, labela:0.5
url2, labelb:0.4
url3, labelc:0.7
```

I was trying to do the following, split the label column by ':' and filter by the numeric value, say greater than 0.6. In the above case, filter out rows with url1 and url2 since the values are 0.5 and 0.4, respectively.

I did the following but this won't work:

`df = df[df["labels"].str.split(':').get(1).astype('float') >= 0.6]`

I guess what happen is that `get(1)` will give me the second row instead of my imaginary second column after split. I also tried a bunch of the variation of this but didn't work. I hope this illustrate my idea though. What would be an elegant way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: This works. `df[df['labels'].str.split(':').str[1].astype(float) >= 0.6]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `df.str.split(..., expand=True)` followed by type conversion to float with `df.astype` and `boolean indexing`:

```
In [782]: df[df['labels'].str.split(':', expand=True)[1].astype(float) >= 0.6]
Out[782]: 
    url       labels
2  url3   labelc:0.7
```

Comment: @ScottBoston I beat you once... you've beaten me tonnes of times... half your up votes are from me :p

Comment: That would imply 100% from you and me :-)

Comment: Verified. Thank you. Looks like `expand=True` is the key.

Answer (score 2):

Long way about a similar approach...
`numpy` has a string manipulation module `np.core.defchararray` with many of the same functions we find under the string accessor `pd.Series.str`

I chose to use [**`rsplit`**](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.core.defchararray.rsplit.html) for no really good reason other than I imagined than I imagined there could be multiple `':'` and wanted to only split off the last one.

```
splits = np.core.defchararray.rsplit(df['labels'].values.astype(str), ':', 1)
df[np.array([x[1] for x in splits], dtype=float) >= .6]

   urls       labels
2  url3   labelc:0.7
```

Comment: What does `defchararray` do here?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ it's just a module containing string manipulation functions.  I use `rsplit`